# How to include required plugins with WordPress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing WordPress theme for the first time. While I distribute theme, I need to suggest required plugin to developer. Is there any way to include used plugin with theme package or suggest required plugin to them in list?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that technically because the plugins and themes are distributed separately. But, you could make a WordPress fork of sorts that includes the plugins together with your theme, and distribute it via Github.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tricky way, [check this](http://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/49518/wordpress-how-to-move-all-your-plugin-code-to-your-theme-file-so-you-think-you-are-not-actually-running-any-plugins#Some_Resources).
But its better to notify user to install required plugins using WordPress.